# Variable-dependent import in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a class where I need to import an external class, but the choice of class to import depends on a variable that isn't known until the class is instantiated. The module file structure is like this:

```
root
| -myclass.py
| -pg
| | -tabledata.py
| -pandas
| | -tabledata.py
```

My class is built to operate on datasets that are stored in several formats (e.g. Pandas, Postgresql) and I need to import the `TableData` class depending on which backend data format is used.

I want to do something like this

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,backend):
        if backend == 'pg':
            from .pg.tabledata import TableData
        elif backend == 'pandas':
            from .pandas.tabledata import TableData
    ...
```

but that doesn't allow me to reference the TableData class elsewhere in MyClass, of course. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: By "of course" you mean "i haven't tested it, but it shouldn't work, of course"? Because that will work.

Comment: Made my post more specific. The import works, but I can't reference it elsewhere in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the class you imported in `__init__` and use it later:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, backend):
        if backend == 'pg':
            from sub1.tabledata import TableData
            self.class_to_create = TableData  # Remember the class, do not create an object
        elif backend == 'pandas':
            from sub2.tabledata import TableData
            self.class_to_create = TableData  # Remember the class, do not create an object

    def gimme_a_table(self):
        return self.class_to_create()  # Create an object whenever you need


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyClass("pandas")
    print(m.gimme_a_table())
    n = MyClass("pg")
    print(n.gimme_a_table())
```

But I'd still prefer to see the imports at the top of the file. You can achieve this by renaming the imports with `as`:

```
from sub1.tabledata import TableData as PgTable
from sub2.tabledata import TableData as PandasTable


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, backend):
        if backend == 'pg':
            self.class_to_create = PgTable  # Remember the class, do not create an object
        elif backend == 'pandas':
            self.class_to_create = PandasTable  # Remember the class, do not create an object

    def gimme_a_table(self):
        return self.class_to_create()  # Create an object whenever you need


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyClass("pandas")
    print(m.gimme_a_table())
    n = MyClass("pg")
    print(n.gimme_a_table())
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can import both and according to some external configuration file or through some flag added when running the code, you can decide which function to call.

Answer (score -1):

The importlib package has a nice import_module method that will help with this. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.